# Flutter TextField: prevent scrolling to cursor position when getting focus

Tags: flutter

The `TextField`'s `enableInteractiveSelection` is false, and the field is out of focus.

Its scroll position is 0.0 (the top). The cursor is at the end of the content.

When you tap into the `TextField`, it will scroll down to its cursor position. How can I prevent this scrolling?